# Is there a standard pattern in Node-RED for processing multiple MQTT topics from each of many identical devices?

Tags: node-red

### Background

I'm building a system to act as a central hub for a large number (tens to tens of thousands) of identical remote telemetry units (RTUs) out in the field.  Each RTU is able to send data over MQTT.  Each has upwards of 80 topics it can send, and it does so whenever one or more of the monitored values changes.  Topics are of the form /*clientid*/*realTopic*, for example `/1234567890/HWMonitor/CPUTemperature` or `/1234567890/GPS/1/Latitude`.  Each client ID is guaranteed to be unique to a single RTU.

I have no control over the firmware of the RTU.  I know the topic has a leading `/`.  I can't change that; I can't merge the messages at source; I can make no change whatsoever.

The RTUs send via radio (4G on a good day, GPRS if that's all that's available).  They are often moving, and may go through dead spots with no reception.  Topics can (and do!) arrive in any order from any RTU, and part of a transmission may be somewhat delayed due to a dead spot.  Multiple RTUs may be transmitting at the same time, and my MQTT broker may interleave messages from multiple RTUs.

### The job

For each RTU, I need to be able to accumulate topics and changed data until it doesn't send anything for a while (timeout is part of the flow's context, generally a few seconds), then persist those changes for that RTU **while identifying them as a batch**.  This is a pretty classic telemetry use case.

I can build a flow in Node-RED so that I can receive data from a single RTU, split off the client ID from the rest of the topic, aggregate data for topics that come in close together (up to a few seconds apart), and store the result where I need it.  Good start!

### Finally, the question!

I don't know the "standard" way to make the above flow work for more than one RTU.  Within a Node-RED flow, is there any existing tooling for - for example - maintaining a timeout for each of several thousand remote units, aggregating payload data across multiple topics for each RTU, then writing+clearing the aggregated data when a timeout comes in for that RTU?

If I have to, I'll build it myself.  But this feels like a pretty common use case.  My search-fu is weak today; either I haven't found the right keywords yet or nobody else is doing this.

Can anyone point me to resources that might help me?  Answered similar questions on here; web pages or blog posts; -contrib nodes that already do this kind of thing; or, failing all those, some headache remedies?  Thanks!

Comment: The fact that trigger nodes filter by `msg.topic` and storing things in the context would be my approach.

Comment: @hardillb - agree, and I'm using the context approach :-).  Can't control what topics come in last, so filtering by topic is - unfortunately - not enormously useful.

Comment: but you can trim the topic back to just the device id at the start of the MQTT topic before feeding it to the trigger node